# Espresso - Validate TextView contents Android

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to write a Expresso Test on Android to validate the TextView content.
When I read the text from resources as below it works

```
    @Test
    public void changeText_newActivity() {
        onView(withId(R.id.mainContent)).check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));
}
```

The above is the test using espresso 
Below is the code on android activity where it works

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    />
```

But When I replace the text using hardcoded text instead of referencing to the resources the test fails and getting the error unable to find the view in the view hierarchy

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:text="Hello world!"
    />
```

Below is the error when I run the test

android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Hello world!"

Appreciated your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Code    "Hello world!"
               ^
Test    "Hello World!"
```

See the difference? `W` and `w` are not the same.

Espresso rightfully cannot find such a view, because there is none mathing.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
onView(withId(R.id.mainContent)).check(matches(withText("Hello world!")));
```

In some case eqaulIgnoreCase also better option.